# Create views have field image with multil image style?

Tags: views, 8, media

I want create view like this

[image: Views Image]

You can see this view have two image style (name are 700x700 and 263x132). I want use two image style because it's faster when the page loading.

So how can do that with views?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Views "Attachment", so you can create main View to display only first two items, then you can create "Attachment" with different markup (remeber to apply this only for current format) and skip first two elements and then attach it to the main view (after it). Sorry for my english ;)